# Gitlab recovery codes regeneration "Permission denied" message

Tags: gitlab

I changed my phone and lost my 2FA app for GitLab.  I don't have a recovery key, so need to generate a new one.  I'm using a free account.

I've found information on how this can be done using `$ ssh git@gitlab.com 2fa_recovery_codes` which the docs say will generate a new list of recovery keys, however I'm getting the message: `git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).`   I'm still able to fetch and push as usual using GitExtensions so I take this to mean I have some stored credentials already, but haven't been able to find anything to help resolve the error.

Can someone point me towards something that would help resolve this, please?

Comment: Do you have a free account or paid?

Comment: It's a free account - I should have included that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was to put my private key in my home directory (%USERPROFILE%) /.ssh subdirectory, so `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` (`C:\Users\GuiJames\.ssh` for me).

The key filename has to be id_rsa (no file extension) for the default naming.

I ran `ssh -vvvv git@gitlab.com` to debug. This told me when the key was accepted.

Once it was working, I used the command `ssh git@gitlab.com 2fa_recovery_codes`, which then prompted me

> Are you sure you want to generate new two-factor recovery codes?
> Any existing recovery codes you saved will be invalidated. (yes/no)

Enter `yes` and it should return a list of single-use recovery codes, e.g.

```
119135e5a3ebce8e
11f6v2a498810dcd
3924c7ab2089c902
e79a3398bfe4f224
34bd7b74adbc8861
f061691d5107df1a
169bf32a18e63e7f
b510e7422e81c947
20dbed24c5e74663
df9d3b9403b9c9f0
```

The official guidance from GitLab on this can be found here:
[Two-factor authentication - GitLab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html)